# Conditional field value in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, calculated-field

I created a database to keep track of customer service related follow-ups in a call centre environment.
My table has, among the others, a Date created field, a Due date field and a Status field (Open, Due or Overdue).

I would like the value indicated in the Status field to update automatically as time elapses.

Can this be achieved and how?

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely possible. Why not?  I would suggest you do the following:

(1) add another status to the status field called 'closed'
(2) determine from a logorithmic perspective what 'Due' means (e.g. if the current date falls within 5 days of your due date
(3) Write a query which updates your status either 'due' or 'overdue' depending on what the current date is

Comment: Thank you very much, an update query will do the job perfectly. As I am sure you can surmise, I am a novice with Access. I will not need to add a 'Closed' value to the Status field since I have a separate field called Completed with a choice of 'Yes' or 'No' values. I have now created an update query, I have indicated 'Overdue' in the 'Update to' row and [Due date] ‹ Date () in the criteria, but I do not know how to add the extra criteria I need: update to 'Due' when [Due date] = Date () and update to 'Open' when [Due date] › Date ()... can you (or anyone else) please provide assistance?

Comment: It seems you just need to write a query using the logic you mentioned above?

Comment: Yes, I just don't know how to write the expression for the 3 criterias.

Comment: How many tables are you working with?  I mean, is the due date located as a field for each record in your table or is it somewhere else (in another table)

Comment: By the way, if you find any of my comments useful, dont forget to 'upvote them' by clicking on the Arrow on the left..

Comment: I have only one table and I want the update query to change the Status field (Open, Due and Overdue) according to the difference between the current date and the Due date.

Comment: what is the date that you want to use to compare the due date?? Today's date?

Comment: Here i have a table with two fields, Status, and DueDate.  This query will update the status field to 'Due' when the due date is less than or equal to today's date:            UPDATE tblDue SET tblDue.Status = "Due"
WHERE (((tblDue.DueDate)<=Now()));

Comment: Yes, today's date. I do not want the Status to read 'Due' unless the Due date is equal to today's date; I would like the status to be 'Open' until then, and change to 'Overdue' after.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE tblDue SET tblDue.Status = "Due"
WHERE (((tblDue.DueDate)=Now()));

UPDATE tblDue SET tblDue.Status = "Overdue"
WHERE (((tblDue.DueDate)>Now()));